# jQuery mouseover/mouseleave event.stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple navigation menu set up – has three main links, and and if you hover over the 'Work' link, a list of 'Works' are overlay'd over the navigation menu.

I have set up a simple jsFiddle to show you what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/gM73q/2/

One problem I am having is if you are hovered over the title 'Work' (which activates the sub menu), then re-hover over 'Work', the menu fades in and fades out. This is obviously the correct behaviour (as the word 'Work' is on a higher z-index than the menu) but I'd like to be able to hover over 'Work' and the menu still remain.

My JS is as follows:

```
$('.site-menu-container ul li:first-child a').on('mouseover', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.site-menu-container .work-menu-container').fadeIn();
}); 
$('.site-menu-container .work-menu-container').on('mouseleave', function(event) {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Any ideas? I'm sure I have to use `event.stopPropagation()` but unsure how.

Thanks,
R

Comment: You could change the document structure so that the sub menus are actually children of each main menu item. Also you probably wnat to use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTimeout to delay the menu fadeout:

```
var hoverTimeout;
$('.site-menu-container ul li:first-child a').on('mouseover', 
    function (event) {
        if(hoverTimeout){
            clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);   
        }
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.site-menu-container .work-menu-container').fadeIn();
    }
);
$('.site-menu-container .work-menu-container').on('mouseleave', 
    function (event) {
        hoverTimeout = setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut();
        }, this),500);
    }
);
```

[Updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gM73q/3/)